# sort vs sortrows in Matlab

Tags: sorting, matlab

Is it possible to achieve the same functionality with sort function than using sortrows.  My matrix has over 4million+ rows and sortrows is bringing in a lot of latency because of iterations. (a vectorizated approach would be appreciated)

```
%Col1 -> date, Col2 -> id, Col3 -> ranking within each date-group (to help you debug)
data = [ ...
       734614 5 3; 734615 6 5; 734622 1 1; 734615 1 1; 734615 4 3; 
       734622 2 2; 734622 4 3;   734615 3 2; 734615 5 4; 734614 3 2; 
       734614 1 1; 734622 8 4; 734622 9 5;] ;

sortedanswer = 
  734614           1           1
  734614           3           2
  734614           5           3
  734615           1           1
  734615           3           2
  734615           4           3
  734615           5           4
  734615           6           5
  734622           1           1
  734622           2           2
  734622           4           3
  734622           8           4
  734622           9           5
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, you are sorting by first column and then by the second column for identical first-column values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it as

```
[~,indx]=sort(data(:,1));
sortedanswer=data(indx,:)

sortedanswer =

      734614           5           3
      734614           3           2
      734614           1           1
      734615           6           5
      734615           1           1
      734615           4           3
      734615           3           2
      734615           5           4
      734622           1           1
      734622           2           2
      734622           4           3
      734622           8           4
      734622           9           5
```

Note that it is sorted by the rows in the first column. The order of the rows is the same as that in the original `data`, which is why you see `5   3` in the second and third columns in the first row in mine.

Comment: Thanks Yoda.  Yes, I know that but would it be possible to modify it somehow to the actual desired answer?  Conversely, imagine 2 matrices: mat1 has 1000 rows mat2 has 4mil rows. mat2 is sorted perfectly.  I need to implement ismember(mat1,mat2) for some cols.  In your experience, would keeping mat1 sorted perfectly increase the speed of ismember?  Thanks!

Comment: @Maddy: If you want it that way, it _would_ involve a series of sorting. For e.g., sort first, then by second, then by third etc., which is what `sortrows` does. I'm not entirely sure if you can make a significant improvement over that, to warrant delving into this deeper.

Comment: Thanks Yoda.  Yeah, you are right.  I'll go ahead and use sortrows.

Comment: @Maddy: In response to the second half of the first comment, I don't think it would offer any speed up, because `ismember` has to go through each member of the anyway and it won't matter if it is sorted or not. For matrices as large as in your example (3 cols each), on my machine, `ismember(mat1,mat2,'rows')` takes 3.25 seconds unsorted and 3.3 seconds sorted, almost the same :)

Comment: Actually, if the keys are sorted you can use ismembc (same arguments as ismember) which is much faster. It's a builtin function that is not documented (I think because checking the inputs to see if they are sorted would be expensive). If you know the keys are sorted, then it offers substantial speed gains.

Comment: @Matlab Sorter -> thanks! It really helps my project. I cut down total computation time from 8.9 hours to 1.5 hours! And im using sorted matrices with no NaNs in them.